# SEO for every page necessary?

Tags: seo, optimization

I would like to know if it's really necessary for every single web page of a website to be SEO optimized?

I mean do many SEO optimized pages boost my ranking in general? Or can I concentrate on the most relevant pages for Google search and forget about pages like impressum or product overviews. Because I don't believe my customers would want to get a product overview in Google search as a result instead of the product page itself. But maybe Google and bing think otherwise.

I appreciate every help, especially with a reference source.

Comment: It is up to you. Focus on what is important first. Then think about the rest. Cheers!!

Comment: 1. What optimisations do you have in mind? 2. Why did you add the tags you added (meta-tags, heading, title-attribute)? Do you mean meta-description? Do you mean heading elements `h1`-`h6`? And what about the `title` attribute? For what?

Comment: @unor 1. I mean choosing the right number of headings, a good heading hierarchy with good wording and one important keyword per page. A optimized keyword-word-ratio. You know the stuff that counts in general but eats up a lot of time =) 2. I added these tags because I think these are the most important factors for seo (except the content itself of course)

Comment: @closetnoc I dont think my boss nor my customers would accept an answer like "I THINK IT'S NOT IMPORTANT" from me. At least not without examples or a reference source.

Comment: I did not say that anything was unimportant. I just said focus on what is the most important. By that, I was referring to pages and not HTML elements as that was what your question is about. As far as keyword to text ratio, this is junk SEO. There is not such cause and effect. If you are asking about basic SEO and what to do, there is a lot of that here already. I have several good answers that will really help you as well as others. Can you be a bit more specific of what you are asking and we will all jump in I am sure. SEO is our thing! Cheers!!

Comment: For the record, it is better that as many pages rank as well as they can. Of course you want some to perform better than others. However, the more content you have that performs well, the better for search performance in general. Inbound (back) links are really helpful. Just make sure you create the best inbound links you can. Go for organic as much as possible. However, waiting for people to link to you is like waiting for dinosaur eggs to hatch. It may not happen. Go social as well. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnec Woah my question was propably more complex then I assumed. "junk SEO" is new to me. I'm gonna read more about that. I guess I'm missing the fundamental basics about SEO. Guess it's better I read a bit more about it before I start a discussion =P Thanks for your help! I'm gonna "accept" it with the answer from Michael Moriarty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an Internet Marketing perspective it is important to 'pre-sell' products. Consumers are much more likely to buy if they are sold on the benefits of the product, not just shown the features and the price tag.

Every webpage should have some goal in mind and a target audience. It should be written with highly searched for keywords in mind. These keywords should be included in the description and throughout the content to be effective. This should not detract from genuine content, however.

A good, easy to follow and updated guide for SEO in 2016 is [The Fundamental Guide to SEO in 2016](http://www.forbes.com/sites/jaysondemers/2015/11/10/the-fundamental-guide-to-seo-in-2016/#5bf6b1cd6322)

Comment: You are welcome. I was going to add that the <meta name="Keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3"> entry in the <head> element of each page is not necessary. I still do it to keep me on track, but Google says it does not look at that for rankings.